# How to get value selected in @Html.DropDownListFor inside the view and pass it to action in OTHER controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a dropdown list. If user chooses to click Fetch call I want to pass id of selected `Call` to action `FetchCall` in controller `Person`.

```
<p>
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), null), new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", style = "width: 500px;" })
</p>
<p>
     @Html.ActionLink("Fetch call","FetchCall", "Person", new { id = HERE_SELECTED_CALL_ID }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-lg" })
</p>
```

View is strongly typed against: `@model WebApplication2.Models.ApplicationUser` and is associated with Action `Details` in controller `ApplicationUsers`.

How to get value selected in  @Html.DropDownListFor inside the view and pass it to action in OTHER controller in my case?

---

If it is not a problem I feel better with java script(I understand better what is going on).

### EDIT

This is solution(mine) which lacks getting value from dropdown in java script function.

The dropdown list:

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), null), new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", style = "width: 500px;" })
```

The button when clicked `javascript:FetchCall()` is invoked:

```
<input type="button" id="FetchCallButton" value="Fetch call" onclick="javascript:FetchCall()" />
```

The JavaScript function:

```
 function FetchCall() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchCall, "Person")';  
        $.post(url, { callToMakeId: SELECTED_CALL_IN_DROPDOWN_ID_HOW_TO_GET_IT}, function (data) {
            alert('YES');
        });
    }
```

The action method in `PersonController`:

```
public ActionResult FetchCall(int callToMakeId) {...}
```

**Question:** How to get selected `call.Id` in the java script function?

---

### EDIT 2

Thanks to Tommy's solution I've been able to read selection in dropdown list. The problem is that I get exacly what is written in the dropdown list which is result from `ToString()` inside `CallToMake` class.

function:

```
function FetchCall() {
    alert($("#CallsToMake").val());
    var url = '@Url.Action("FetchCall", "Person")';
    $.post(url, { callToMakeId: $("#CallsToMake").val() }, function (data) {
        alert('YES');
    });
}
```

I show in image below contents of the drop down and alert `alert($("#CallsToMake").val());`:

[image]

The only solution that comes to my mind is to display `id` of the call in the dropdown list and then cut it out in the controller action. It sounds bad, isn't it?

### EDIT 3

The list finally looks like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), "Id","Id"), new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", style = "width: 500px;" })
```

java script:

```
    function FetchCall() {
        alert($("#CallsToMake").val());
        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchCall", "Person")';
        $.post(url, { callToMakeId: $("#CallsToMake").val() }, function (data) {
            alert('YES');
        });
    }
=
```

and the Action method

```
 public ActionResult FetchCall(int callToMakeId) {
            CallToMake callToMake = db.CallsToMake.Find(callToMakeId);
            int idPersonToCall = callToMake.Callee.Id;
            db.CallsToMake.Remove(callToMake);
            db.SaveChanges();
            Debug.WriteLine("I AM HERE");
            return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = idPersonToCall });
        }
```

Action method is being invoked but I am not redirected anywhere. Method just runs and that is all.

Comment: This link could help you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10499797/javascript-variable-carry-an-id-that-i-need-to-use-in-a-html-actionlink

Comment: You will need to use javascript/jquery.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Could you please have a look at the edit? I posted solution with javascript which lacks getting selected value from the list in the script.

Comment: @Yoda, Tommy's answer should work for you

Comment: @StephenMuecke It worked partialy as I can see what has been selected but cannot get to the **id** of selected value, I posted only solution that I can think of in EDIT 2.

Comment: @Yoda, you need to construct the select list using the overload that accepts the values for `text` and `value`. I dont know the name of the properties, but it will be something like `..new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake, "NameofValueProperty", NameofTextProperty")`. The `NameofValueProperty` is the ID property to want to get and the `NameofTextProperty` is what will be displayed

Comment: @StephenMuecke This worked! The deal is that I have not been redirected to the view action method in controller `FetchCall` returns. The action method runs to the en I used `Debug.WriteLine` to check it. I posted action method in `EDIT 3`.

Comment: No, because you are doing an AJAX call (so you stay on the same page). I'll post an answer showing how to do a redirect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you need to construct your `SelectList` using the overload that accepts a `DataValueField` and `TextValueField`. [Refer documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505286(v=vs.118).aspx). This might look something like

```
... new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake, "CallID", "CallName"), ..
```

Script (this assumes you remove the `onclick` attribute from the button)

```
$('#FetchCallButton').click(function() {
  var url = '@Url.Action("FetchCall, "Person")';
  var callID = $("#CallsToMake").val();
  window.location.href = url + '/' + callID; // redirect to /Person/FetchCall/3
});
```

Comment: I'm using [Select tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms#the-select-tag-helper). Using `@Stephen`'s code I was able to get the id of selected item as follows: `<select asp-for="SelectedProjYr" asp-items="Model.lstProjYears"></select>` **var selectedItemVal = $('#SelectedProjYr').val();**

Answer (score 4):

It should be straight-forward.  The model property name will be the id of the element Razor generates - like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CallsToMake, new SelectList(Model.CallsToMake.OrderByDescending(call => call.TimeStamp), null), new { @class = "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle", style = "width: 500px;" })
```

would generate

```
<select id="CallsToMake" name="CallsToMake" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" style="width: 500px">
    <option value="1">Some person</option>
</select>
```

Combining this knowledge with the jQuery call to get an element by id - `$("#elementId")`, we can then send the selected value back using an AJAX request.

```
function FetchCall() {
        var url = '@Url.Action("FetchCall, "Person")';  
        $.post(url, { callToMakeId: $("#CallsToMake").val()}, function (data) {
            alert('YES');
        });
    }
```

Comment: Tommy this solution enabled me to get selected contents from the dropdown list but I don't have access to the id, please look at EDIT 2. I presented there my results.

Comment: This line was the both the most simple and the most useful thing I read today! **The model property name will be the id of the element Razor generates**

Comment: nice one and work well. if  you can please tell me if we have more than one dropdownlist, how to call for both in script. I tried by changing the id, but then it returns only last one.No idea about that.If you can please help me with this. @Tommy

Comment: @Tommy Using yours (as well as `@StephenMuecke`s) code I was able to get the id in case of select tag helper as shown in my comment to `@Stephen`s response above.

Answer (score 0):

thanx for @Tommy it works for me. but I had a problem about if I had to return from two dropdowlists how to do it in query. then I found a way and I think it will help to others.

```
function fetch(){
     var url = '@Url.Action("resultView","Test")';
            $.post(url, { LocationID: $("#location_ID").val(), TypeID:$("#type_ID").val() }, function (data) {
                alert('YES');
            });
}
```

this works for me fine.